# MongoDB expression to create document if document *with value* does not already exist

Tags: mongodb, document

So, lets say I have the following structure:

```
{
    value: 'test',
    property: 'good'
}
```

and I want to create a NEW document with property 'good' but only if it does not already exist with that value {property: 'good'}
So running the query will return a new document:
{
value: 'test2',
property: 'good'
}
Pretty much like unique true indexes work, but all in the same query.

I can always find first and check if it returns null and then proceed to create it, but is there any operator to do it into the same query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use update with upsert: true, like this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fr-U4lHhtj8)

Comment: This is  not the expected behavior. That query will modify if exist or create a new doc if it doesn't, I don't want to  modify anything existing.